# Can the geometric proof of "$A^{2} = A$ implies $(I - A)^{2} = (I - A)$" be generalized to non-diagonalizable matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix (say a real matrix, but I believe this applies over any field). It is straightforward to show algebraically that if $A^{2} = A$, then $(I - A)^{2} = I - A$. I recently found a more "geometric" proof for the special case of diagonalizable matrices:

Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix similar to $A$. Since $A^{2} = A$, we have that the eigenvalues of $A$ are 1 or 0, so the diagonal entries of $D$ are 1 or 0. This also holds for $I - D$, implying that $(I - D)^{2} = I - D$. Since this is similar to $I - A$, we have $(I - A)^{2} = I - A$.

Is there a way to generalize this argument to include the non-diagonalizable case? My guess is that it involves the singular value decomposition, but I'm not familiar enough with that to say.

Comment: If $A^2=A$ you have that $A(A-1)=0$ which tells you that this matrix can be diagonalized. So your proof holds.

Comment: Well,idempotent matrix(matrix $A$ such that $A^2=A$) is always diagonalizable,so your condition never comes true.Anyway it's clever for you to propose a new idea.

Comment: Why cant you just multiply out $(I-A)^2 = I-IA - AI + A^2$ If $A^2 = A,$ and of course $AI = IA = A$ then $(I-A)^2 = (I-A)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A “geometric” view.

If $A=A^2$, let $U=C(A)$, the column space of $A$. Suppose $v\in F^n$ ($F$ the base field). Then
$$
v=Av+(v-Av)=Av+(I-A)v
$$
and $v-Av\in N(A)$, the null space of $A$, because $A(v-Av)=Av-A^2v=0$.

Moreover, if $w\in C(A)\cap N(A)$, then $w=Ax$ for some $x$ and
$$
0=Aw=A(Ax)=A^2x=Ax=w
$$

Thus $F^n=C(A)\oplus N(A)$. Now notice that $A$ is the projection on $C(A)$ along $N(A)$ and that $I-A$ is the projection on $N(A)$ along $C(A)$, so $(I-A)^2=I-A$.

---

On the other hand, if you take a basis of $C(A)$ and a basis of $N(A)$, you obtain a basis of $F^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$, hence $A$ is diagonalizable.